# PHPUnit color output by default IF supported

Tags: phpunit, command-line-interface, ansi-colors

By default PHPUnit does not use colour output. One can add the `--colors` flag to the `phpunit` command or add `colors="true"` to the config file.

I'd like to have colors by default and hence have the setting in my config file. This is nice since I can then run `phpunit` rather than `phpunit --colors` most of the time. However I do have one place where the terminal does not support color output. When colors are enabled there, it makes the output less readable.

Is it possible to keep colors on by default and disable it for this specific terminal? There appears to be no `--no-colors` flag or similar. And ideally I'd not have to specify this anywhere to begin with, and be able to specify something like `colors="auto"`, which then detects if the terminal supports ANSI colors or not.

Comment: Looks like PHPUnit 4.4 add a feature to only enable colors when output to a terminal: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/1458

Answer (score 3):

If you are working under a unix like terminal you could add the following to your .bash_profile

```
alias phpunitc='phpunit --colors'
```

In this way you could have colors calling `phpunitc`, and no colors calling `phpunit` (this would require that you remove the `colors="true"` setting from the configuration file).